# Weird transparent to color gradient in Firefox

Tags: firefox, gradient, transparent

I create my new portfolio and I have weird problem with gradient in CSS. I used CSS Gradient Generator for gradient **transparent** to **violet** to **violet**. Of course there are multiple lines for older browsers too in my code, but W3C line looks like that:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(42,28,80,0.29) 29%,rgba(42,28,80,1) 100%);
```

And I get very strange behaviour on Firefox.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cN1M.jpg

To bring out bug, for that code:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(42,28,80,1) 29%,rgba(42,28,80,1) 100%);
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Utrgr.jpg

It looks like that gradient doesn't know how to do transition between rgba(255,255,255,0) to violet **when there is image under it**. I changed my image in background to normal colour and gradient was good. Is it possible to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed in Firefox 36 by [bug 591600](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=591600)

From Firefox 36 onwards gradients will use premultiplied colours which will make transforming to/from transparent work the way you expect it to.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to fix it also on version lower than Firefox 36.

Firefox had problem to generate nice-looking transition between white transparent and color, the easiest way to fix it is to change first alpha-0 color to the same color as in alpha-1, so this:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(42,28,80,1) 100%);
```

should be changed into:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(42,28,80,0) 0%, rgba(42,28,80,1) 100%);
```